# Points at integer distance

Tags: geometry, general-topology, analytic-geometry

How many points can one can place in $\mathbb{R}^n$, with the requirement that no $n+1$ points lie in the same $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$-plane, and the euclidean distance between every two points is an integer?

Comment: @J.M. if $n+1=3$ then $n-1=1$ so the condition reduces to "no three points in a line".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take $n=2$. By an old result of [Erdős and Anning,](http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1945-01.pdf) there is an infinite collection of points on the unit circle such that all mutual distances are rational.  By scaling up by $K!$ for large $K$, this means that for any integer $k$, we can find a circle, and $k$ points on that circle, such that all mutual distances are integers.

In the same paper, Erdős and Anning show that if we have an *infinite* collection of points in the plane such that all mutual distances are integers, then these points must lie in a line.

The paper referred to above is quite accessible.

Comment: It is for this reason that one usually also imposes the restriction that no $4$ points lie on a circle. In this case there known examples of 7 points in the plane.

Comment: @GerryMyerson But the source linked above (on the second page, start reading from where the first paragraph starts (the odd number $m^2$ with many divisors)) seems to give an arbitrary number of points (for example more than your "7") where just one is outside of the $y$ axis. Clearly no four of those are on a circle. But maybe we must take a line as a "degenerate" circle here, and also disallow four points on a shared line?

Comment: @Jeppe, look at the original question. We're assuming all along, no three points on a line. The circle restriction is in addition to the line restriction. That's why I used the word, "also".

Answer (score 2):

As a lower bound: n+1, arranged in a simplex (triangle/tetahedron/etc.)

In the case n=2, you can do four points: (0,0) (0,3) (4,0) (4,3)... or you can use any Pythagorean triple {a,b,c} and place points at (0,0) (0,a) (b,0) (b,a). However, that approach cannot be extended beyond n=2, as there are no known cuboids with integer sides and all-integer diagonals.

Answer (score 2):

With the restriction no three points in a line, no four points on a circle, there is a 7 point configuration on the plane. I came here to ask about the upper bound in 3-space, with the added restriction no 4 points on a plane.

[1] Tobias Kreisel and Sascha Kurz, There are integral heptagons, no three points on a line, no four on a circle, Discrete Comput. Geom. 39 (2008), no. 4, 786–790, MR2413160 (2009d:52021)
[labeled diagram](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/LabelingTheIntegerHeptagon/)