# Octagon with Integer sides and Integer diagonals

Tags: geometry, integers

I want an octagon or nonagon with integer sides and integer diagonals, and all the lines that connect the vertices to the middle should be integers as well. If that line that connect to the middle as integer is not possible with the other requirements then I can do with a shape with just the first 2 requirements. By diagonals I mean this:

[image: diagonals of octagon]

and the third optional requirement refers to this:

[image: segments connected to the center]

Is this possible? Thanks

Comment: See [points at integer distance](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85309/points-at-integer-distance) for polygons with just the first two requirements.

Comment: Based on answers in the link pointed out by @JaapScherphuis
(in particular, the result by [Erdős and Anning](http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1945-01.pdf)),
it is possible. An example is the cyclic octagon with vertices at $(\pm 4056, \pm 1183)$, $(\pm 3000, \pm 2975)$ and circumradius $4225$.